# Angular DataTables sending three request initially to server

Tags: angularjs, typescript, datatable, angular-datatables

I'm using `Angular DataTables` library. Every thing is working fine(properly loading data in datatables) but i don't know why initially it sending 3 `http` request to the server on given url . I have searched but didn't find any solution.

Version: v0.5.5

[Library link](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables)

[Library Documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/index.html)

Below is the code just called one time but sending three request to the server.

```
getData() {

            var authorization = this.$http.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"];

            var self = this;
            debugger;
            this.dtOptions = this.dTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
                .withOption('ajax',
                {
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    url: self.url,//server url to get data
                    type: "POST",
                    headers: { 'Authorization': authorization },
                    data(data) {

                        data.dataTableModel = self.dataTableModel;
                        data.order[0].name = data.columns[data.order[0].column].data;
                        data.query = data.search.value;

                        return JSON.stringify(data);
                    },
                    error(errorResponse) {
                        console.log(errorResponse);
                    }
                })
                .withDataProp('data')
                .withOption('processing', true)
                .withOption('serverSide', true)
                .withOption('createdRow', (row, data, dataIndex) => {//row recompile

                    this.$compile(angular.element(row).contents())(this.$scope);
                })
                .withOption('headerCallback', header => {//header recompile
                    this.dtOptions.headerCompiled = true;
                    this.$compile(angular.element(header).contents())(this.$scope);

                })
                .withPaginationType("simple_numbers")
                // .withOption("scrollY", 150)
                // .withOption("Paging",false)
                .withOption("lengthMenu", [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]])
                .withBootstrap();
        }
```

*On Image you can see the three consecutive requests*

Any suggestion ?

[image]

Comment: Do you call `getData` 3 times?

Comment: @MaximShoustin no. Just call it 1 time .

Comment: I have make sure that it only call once not 3 times